# How to construct then'able chain using promise without nesting the `then()` functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, promise, bluebird

I try to perform certain tasks for each key exists in Redis. `Promise` has been implemented to **overcome callback hell**. So that I have tried to assign each function executions into variables and then tried making them into `thenable chain` as given in the following code. The `thenable` is working fine at the first step, but not working as desired afterwards.

Please look into the following code. The following code has some dependent `js` files that i have not i but it seems to be written/handled But, it seems that I end-up with nested `thenable chanins` even after using promise.I guess i am handling promises in wrong way.ncluded.

```
var redis = require('redis');
var client = redis.createClient();
var promise = require('bluebird');
var yaml = require('node-yaml-config');
var config = yaml.load(__dirname + '/config.yaml');
var analyticsQueue = require(config.ANALYTICSQUEUE);
var queueOpsObj = require(__dirname + '/' + config.ANALYTICSQUEUE + 'Operations.js').QueueOps;


var queueOps = new queueOpsObj(null,'test');
var getAllKeys = queueOps.getAllKeys().then(function(result){

        return result;
});

var dequeueAllResultObj = getAllKeys.then(function(keyCollection){

    promise.map(keyCollection, function(key){

        return setInterval(function(){

            var queueOps = new queueOpsObj(null, key);
            queueOps.dequeueAll().then(function(dequeueAllResult){

                console.log('*****' + dequeueAllResult);
                return result;
            }); 

        }, 3000);
    });

});
dequeueAllResultObj.then(function(result){
     // Getting undefined as result   
     console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: I don't see any nested `then`s in your code?

Comment: You need to `return` the result of `Promise.map` from the `then` callback to chain onto it.

Comment: `setInterval` does not result in a promise. There's no point in `return`ing it.